# Android emulator get terminated while doing scroll up in the screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using windows 11, Android Studio with latest version. Created an emulator in android studio with config as:
RAM - 2048
VM Heap - 1024
Internal - 8912
my Windows 11 has 16GB RAM.

But sometimes when I am doing scrolling up on screen emulator get terminated.

How can I resolve this issue, to prevent termination of the emulator on scroll up event? Rest of the things are working fine only scroll up event on emulator gives termination of emulator every time.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73244820/edit) your post to include CPU/GPU specs along with how you've enabled virtualization (HAXM or other) and any error logs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

wipe data from android emulator then check once.

Comment: Won't work this for me. Also created new emulator same with all emulators.

Comment: it's problem with SDK, try to uninstall first then install once the android studio.

Comment: Reinstalled everything.. Now its working fine.